# Visual Flow Approval

Tags: visual-workflow, flow, visual-flows, approve-action

From my visual flow, I need to approve a record that's in the pending stage of an approval process.  I've been able to get as far as creating a flow that gets the pending ProcessInstance of the record in need of approval.  What's the next step?  Should I Fast Create a ProcessInstance record with an Approved status and a related ProcessWorkItem record?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "Submit for Approval" option under Static Actions ?

[image]

Comment: The challenge is not submitting the record for approval, it's approving a record that's already been submitted for approval.

Comment: @SF1Dev: how did u sort this out? did u write trigger ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot recall and I no longer have access to that org to take a look.  I do recall though that I ended up not using visual flow for the approval.